# Печать текста на принтере через мое приложение?

Tags: android

Как сделать что бы когда я нажал на кнопку в своем приложение он расспечатал текст (String food) на принтере который подключон к планшету

Answer (score 1):

Вариант первый и основной. Печать стандартными средствами описана [в "Курсах" в официальной документации.](https://developer.android.com/training/printing/index.html)

Вариант второй, если принтер экзотический или специализированный, подключается по BlueTooth. В этом случае вам нужна документация к принтеру. Там будут описаны или способ подключения и команды, либо будет предложено воспользоваться поставляемой с принтером библиотекой.